# SequelizeDatabaseError: permission denied for relation notice_opened_tbl

Tags: node.js, postgresql, kubernetes, sequelize.js

I created a new table in Postgres, and I am having issues accessing it with Sequelize. I have already GRANTED all permissions to the table theoretically, and I can use the same account to access the table via my DB GUI.

Is there some additional permission needed for this relationship?

```
Executing (default): SELECT date_trunc('day', "created_at"), COUNT("id") AS "COUNT" FROM "notice_opened_tbl" AS "notice_opened_tbl" WHERE "notice_opened_tbl"."merchant_id" = 40 GROUP BY date_trunc('day', "created_at") ORDER BY date_trunc('day', "created_at") ASC;
(node:45) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: permission denied for relation notice_opened_tbl
```

EDIT: Current permissions - as you can see, they look correct. The user I am trying to connect with right now is postgresadmin (will be changed before production)

[image: permissions]

EDIT: I don't think it is related to the permissions - I've tried virtually everything related to them, **and the query worked when I connected to the database from my local machine, but not from dev**. The issue is only with this one newly created table though.

Also, this is on AWS if it helps anyone

Here is my dev setup - all queries BUT the query involving the new table works from here:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE_NAME || "DATABASENAMEHERE",
    process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME || "postgresadmin",
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD || "PASSWORDHERE",
    {
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || "postgres",
        dialect: "postgres",
        port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT || 5432,
        pool: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000,
        },
        define: {
            timestamps: false,
        },
    });
```

Here is my local setup, which works from my local machine - the query works from here:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE_NAME || "DATABASEHERE",
    process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME || "postgresadmin",
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD || "PASSWORDHERE",
    {
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || "localhost",
        dialect: "postgres",
        port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT || 5465,
        pool: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000,
        },
        define: {
            timestamps: false,
        },
    });
```

In dev, the host is postgres because that's the Kubernetes service associated with the database connection

Here's the code for the query (it is not cleaned up yet):

```
let merchantId = parseInt(req.param("merchantId"), 10);
let noticeWhere = {
       merchant_id: merchantId,
    };
    if (req.query.startdate && req.query.enddate) {
        // @ts-ignore
        noticeWhere.created_at = {
            [Op.between]: [req.query.startdate, req.query.enddate]
        };

    }

    let noticesOpened = NoticeOpened.aggregate(
        "id",
        "COUNT", {
            plain: false,
            where: noticeWhere,
            group: [sequelize.fn("date_trunc", "day", sequelize.col("created_at"))],
            order: [
                [sequelize.fn("date_trunc", "day", sequelize.col("created_at")), "ASC"]
            ],
        });
    return noticesOpened;
```

YAML output for the postgres Kubernetes service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2019-07-21T02:44:44Z","name":"postgres","namespace":"default","resourceVersion":"169556","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/postgres","uid":"7ef0a60f-ab61-11e9-8d66-06505b5dee68"},"spec":{"externalName":"URLHERE","ports":[{"port":5432,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":5432}],"sessionAffinity":"None","type":"ExternalName"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}}
  creationTimestamp: 2019-11-23T00:07:00Z
  name: postgres
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "14358655"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/postgres
  uid: 2c1a58a4-0d85-11ea-a8cb-02dead532c7a
spec:
  externalName: URLHERE
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ExternalName
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Are you shure the sequelize user has granted access to the table?
you can execute `SELECT grantee, privilege_type FROM information_schema.role_table_grants WHERE table_name='mytable'` to check.

Comment: Already checked this. I'll edit the answer to add the relevant data

Comment: @CecilRodriguez Have you granted permissions to the SCHEMA?

Comment: @Matt Is that not the information_schema above? How would I check that

Comment: @CecilRodriguez What user are you logged in as?

Comment: @Matt postgresadmin

Comment: @CecilRodriguez  can you show your sequelize database conection? (without ip or password). Also this query tells you if your user has access to the schemas of the database: `WITH "names"("name") AS (SELECT n.nspname AS "name" FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema') SELECT "name", pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege('postgresadmin', "name", 'CREATE') AS "create", pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege('postgresadmin', "name", 'USAGE') AS "usage" FROM "names";`

Comment: @Dan - that query says that postgresadmin has create and usage access to "public" schema. Also I added the connection details to my question

Comment: For what I can read, it works on your local machine? only on the AWS doesn't work? is your local machine connected to the same database?

Comment: @Dan Correct, when I try to connect via my local machine, the query works fine. When I try to connect from the AWS server, the connection works fine, all other queries work fine, but this specific query fails, even with the same credentials

Comment: What is the sequelize code for the query?

Comment: @Dan Added it. It's not cleaned up yet, but it's a fairly simple count on a newly created NoticeOpened table. I can also add the table schema from sequelize if you'd like

Comment: Can you run this other query? `select tableowner from pg_tables where tablename = 'notice_opened_tbl';` the result should be postgresadmin.

Comment: @Dan The result is postgresadmin

Comment: Just to test it, can you run the plain query with sequelize? `sequelize.query( "SELECT date_trunc('day', created_at), COUNT(id) AS COUNT FROM notice_opened_tbl AS notice_opened_tbl WHERE notice_opened_tbl.merchant_id = 40 GROUP BY date_trunc('day', created_at) ORDER BY date_trunc('day', created_at) ASC;" )`.

Comment: @Dan Same error: Executing (default): SELECT "name", "id", "short_description", "logo", "created_at", "cover_photo", "phone_number", "email", "subscription_status", "stripe_subscription" FROM "merchant_tbl" AS "merchant_tbl" ORDER BY "merchant_tbl"."id" ASC;
(node:45) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: permission denied for relation notice_opened_tbl

Comment: @Dan This was apparently due to my Kubernetes service somehow redirecting to a different user account for postgres. Looking into it further. I add to grant permissions to an entirely different username, despite having the sequelize creds above.

Comment: Seriously? I was thinking kubernetes was the cause XD
Try to see kubernetes configuration... I think it should not overlap your sequelize user.

Comment: @Dan Yeah, I have no idea how it redirected - I see absolutely nothing in my postgres service in Kubernetes that references the other username or anything else. I'll include the YAML output

Comment: @Dan Maybe the UID set in the service?

Comment: To be totally sure, run this query `SELECT DISTINCT usename FROM pg_stat_activity;` It tells you which users connected to your database. You have to run your service and then run this query to check exactly which users connected to the database.

Comment: @Dan Yep, it definitely connected as a different user than my Sequelize connection settings specified. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

> SCHEMANAME fill in

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA SCHEMANAME TO postgresadmin;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON notice_opened_tbl IN SCHEMA SCHEMANAME TO postgresadmin;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA SCHEMANAME to postgresadmin

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE notice_opened_tbl TO postgresadmin;
```

Comment: Still permission denied (used SCHEMANAME as public).

Answer (score 1):

The permission denied for relation error is a general PostgreSQL error meaning that the user that's connected to the database doesn't have access to write or read a specific table.

[DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) do not change permissions for existing objects.They are the default privileges for newly created objects and only for the particular role they belong to. If you do not define the role when running ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES, it defaults to the current role (when executing the ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES statement.

Common causes of this error are as follows:

- If you have created a new credential for your database, you'll need to configure the appropriate permissions for this credential well.
- Row limits also may be the reason for this error.

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO someuser;

you can simply move that GRANT ALL.. query all the way down to the bottom (the point where you created all the necessary table for your database). You can check the [link](https://poanchen.github.io/blog/2018/03/07/How-to-fix-permission-denied-for-relation-some_table_name-in-PostgreSQL)

Comment: I've run the GRANT ALL... command several times, so I do not think that is the case

Comment: Can confirm. This makes no difference in Sequelize. Outside of the ORM, it all works as expected. It has to be something in the Sequelize configuration.